# How to have the ListView smooth scrollbar in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In a ListView when your items don't have the same size the scrollbar change size during scrolling, if it have to go from a 10dp height to 20dp it will go steps by steps (11dp, 12dp, etc etc) so the scrollbar will look smooth.

However in a RecyclerView the behavior is not the same, the scrollbar will jump from 10dp to 20dp instantaneously causing it to look bad.

How to have the same scrollbar as ListView in a ReyclerView ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the behavior of the scrollbars in a RecyclerView by extending the class and implementing [`computeVerticalScrollRange()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#computeVerticalScrollRange()), [`computeVerticalScrollOffset()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#computeVerticalScrollOffset()) and [`computeVerticalScrollExtent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#computeVerticalScrollExtent()).

Here is how i have done it :

```
package com.franckrj.jva.utils

import android.content.Context
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View

class SmoothScrollbarRecyclerView : RecyclerView {
    /* Saving these values only work because functions are (i think) always called in
     * the order range > offset > extent. If, for whatever reason, it doesn't work
     * you can still replace these by a call to the corresponding function. */
    private var lastAverageSizeOfOneItemComputed: Double = 0.0
    private var lastRangeComputed: Int = 0
    private var lastOffsetComputed: Int = 0

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle)

    override fun computeVerticalScrollRange(): Int {
        val linearLm: LinearLayoutManager? = layoutManager as? LinearLayoutManager

        return if (linearLm != null) {
            if (scrollbarNeedToBeShown(linearLm)) {
                lastAverageSizeOfOneItemComputed = computeAverageSizeOfOneItem(linearLm)
                lastRangeComputed = (lastAverageSizeOfOneItemComputed * adapter.itemCount).toInt()
                lastRangeComputed
            } else {
                0
            }
        } else {
            super.computeVerticalScrollRange()
        }
    }

    override fun computeVerticalScrollOffset(): Int {
        val linearLm: LinearLayoutManager? = layoutManager as? LinearLayoutManager

        return if (linearLm != null) {
            if (scrollbarNeedToBeShown(linearLm)) {
                val firstItemPosition: Int = linearLm.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
                val firstItem: View = linearLm.findViewByPosition(firstItemPosition)

                lastOffsetComputed = ((firstItemPosition + getFractionOfItemTopNotVisible(firstItem)) * lastAverageSizeOfOneItemComputed).toInt()
                lastOffsetComputed
            } else {
                0
            }
        } else {
            super.computeVerticalScrollOffset()
        }
    }

    override fun computeVerticalScrollExtent(): Int {
        val linearLm: LinearLayoutManager? = layoutManager as? LinearLayoutManager

        return if (linearLm != null) {
            if (scrollbarNeedToBeShown(linearLm)) {
                val lastItemPosition: Int = linearLm.findLastVisibleItemPosition()
                val lastItem: View = linearLm.findViewByPosition(lastItemPosition)

                lastRangeComputed - lastOffsetComputed - (((adapter.itemCount - 1 - lastItemPosition) + getFractionOfItemBottomNotVisible(lastItem)) * lastAverageSizeOfOneItemComputed).toInt()
            } else {
                0
            }
        } else {
            super.computeVerticalScrollExtent()
        }
    }

    private fun scrollbarNeedToBeShown(linearLm: LinearLayoutManager): Boolean {
        val firstItemPosition: Int = linearLm.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()

        return (firstItemPosition != NO_POSITION && (linearLm.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() > 0 || linearLm.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() < (adapter.itemCount - 1)))
    }

    private fun computeAverageSizeOfOneItem(linearLm: LinearLayoutManager): Double {
        var proportionnalSizeOfVisiblesItems = 0
        var numberOfItemsComputed: Double
        val firstItemPosition: Int = linearLm.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
        val firstItem: View = linearLm.findViewByPosition(firstItemPosition)
        val lastItemPosition: Int = linearLm.findLastVisibleItemPosition()

        if (firstItemPosition != lastItemPosition) {
            val lastItem: View = linearLm.findViewByPosition(lastItemPosition)
            val fractionOfScreenOccupedByFirstItem: Double = getFractionOfScreenOccupedByItem(firstItem)
            val fractionOfScreenOccupedByLastItem: Double = getFractionOfScreenOccupedByItem(lastItem)

            proportionnalSizeOfVisiblesItems += (getViewOutsideHeight(firstItem) * fractionOfScreenOccupedByFirstItem).toInt()
            proportionnalSizeOfVisiblesItems += (getViewOutsideHeight(lastItem) * fractionOfScreenOccupedByLastItem).toInt()
            numberOfItemsComputed = fractionOfScreenOccupedByFirstItem + fractionOfScreenOccupedByLastItem

            for (posIndex: Int in (firstItemPosition + 1)..(lastItemPosition - 1)) {
                proportionnalSizeOfVisiblesItems += getViewOutsideHeight(linearLm.findViewByPosition(posIndex))
                numberOfItemsComputed += 1.0
            }
        } else {
            /* Only one item is visible, so we assume that every items have his height. */
            proportionnalSizeOfVisiblesItems = getViewOutsideHeight(firstItem)
            numberOfItemsComputed = 1.0
        }

        return (proportionnalSizeOfVisiblesItems / numberOfItemsComputed)
    }

    private fun getFractionOfScreenOccupedByItem(item: View): Double {
        val tmpFractionOfScreenOccupedByItem: Double = (minOf(getRecyclerViewInsideBottom(), getViewOutsideBottom(item)) - maxOf(getRecyclerViewInsideTop(), getViewOutsideTop(item))) / getRecyclerViewInsideBottom().toDouble()
        /* Just in case, but it's probably useless. */
        return tmpFractionOfScreenOccupedByItem.coerceIn(0.0, 1.0)
    }

    private fun getFractionOfItemTopNotVisible(item: View): Double {
        val tmpFractionOfItemTopNotVisible: Double = maxOf(getRecyclerViewInsideTop() - getViewOutsideTop(item), 0) / getViewOutsideHeight(item).toDouble()
        /* Just in case, but it's probably useless. */
        return tmpFractionOfItemTopNotVisible.coerceIn(0.0, 1.0)
    }

    private fun getFractionOfItemBottomNotVisible(item: View): Double {
        val tmpFractionOfItemBottomNotVisible: Double = maxOf(getViewOutsideBottom(item) - getRecyclerViewInsideBottom(), 0) / getViewOutsideHeight(item).toDouble()
        /* Just in case, but it's probably useless. */
        return tmpFractionOfItemBottomNotVisible.coerceIn(0.0, 1.0)
    }

    private fun getViewOutsideTop(view: View): Int {
        val layoutParam = view.layoutParams as RecyclerView.LayoutParams
        return view.top - layoutParam.topMargin
    }

    private fun getViewOutsideBottom(view: View): Int {
        val layoutParam = view.layoutParams as RecyclerView.LayoutParams
        return view.bottom + layoutParam.bottomMargin
    }

    private fun getViewOutsideHeight(view: View): Int {
        return getViewOutsideBottom(view) - getViewOutsideTop(view)
    }

    private fun getRecyclerViewInsideTop(): Int {
        return paddingTop
    }

    private fun getRecyclerViewInsideBottom(): Int {
        return height - paddingBottom
    }
}
```

My implementation only work if you use a LinearLayoutManager, otherwise it will just use the default implementation. It also take into account the margins of items inside the RecyclerView and the padding of the RecyclerView.

Basically i just compute the average size of an item based on items currently visibles, the smooth transitions between sizes is done by only using a percentage of the size of items that are partially visible, the percentage used is (visible height of item) / (total height of RecyclerView).

When you know the average size of an item you know the total size of the list by multiplying it by the number of items, you know the top offset of the thumb by multiplying the number of items totally hidden above the list plus the size of the hidden top part of the first item (exprimed between 0 and 1) by the average size of an item, and you know the size of the thumb by computing the bottom offset of the thumb the same way you computed the top offset.